# Generate statistics in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8.

I have schema:

```
Schema::create('statistics', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->text('agent')->nullable();
    $table->date('date')->nullable();
    $table->ipAddress('ip');
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->default(0);
    $table->bigInteger('quest_id')->default(0);
    $table->string('browser', 70)->nullable();
    $table->string('platform', 70)->nullable();
    $table->string('language', 12)->nullable();
    $table->engine = "InnoDB";
    $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
    $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
});
```

I get statistics from this function:

```
public function generateStatistics(string $dateFrom, string $dateTo, int $id)
{
    return Statistics::whereBetween('date', [$dateFrom, $dateTo])->where('user_id', $id)->get();
}

$statisticsTotal = $this->frontendRepository->generateStatistics($dateFrom, $dateTo, $request->user()->id);
$statisticsResultsTotal = [];

$period = CarbonPeriod::create($dateFromInput, '1 day', $dateToInput);
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    $date = $dt->format("Y-m-d");
    $count = 0;
    $count2 = 0;
    foreach ($statisticsTotal as $stat){
        if ($stat->date == $date){
            $count = $count + 1;
        }
    }
    array_push($statisticsResultsTotal, "$date|$count");
};
```

This code generate statistics. It's work fine.
Now I need generate unique visit statistics
Unique = unique IP.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go on with the same logic you have, a simple **groupBy** will suffice.

You can generate another function for it like this:

```
public function generateUniqueStatistics(string $dateFrom, string $dateTo, int $id)
{
    return Statistics::whereBetween('date', [$dateFrom, $dateTo])->where('user_id', $id)->groupBy('ip')->get();
}
```

This way you can just change the calling to:

```
$statisticsTotal = $this->frontendRepository->generateUniqueStatistics($dateFrom, $dateTo, $request->user()->id);
```

and rest code will just work with it as its in the same format.

#### Update

I thought it was obvious but, just to be clear, in order for a **groupBy** to run without having the **select** columns in it, you will need to run your mySql in non strict mode.

Inside your `config/database.php` file, you will find an array `connections`, under which there is a key `mysql`, set its property `strict` as `false`.

If you do not want to do that and keep going with strict mysql, just give the columns name you are interested in to select, and do not include id, as id is not relevant here when selecting the statistics grouping by ip.

So for example, let's say you need `company_id` and `agent`, you can do like this:

```
return Statistics::whereBetween('date', [$dateFrom, $dateTo])->where('user_id', $id)->select('company_id','agent','ip')->groupBy('ip')->get();
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Thx for yours answer. This function return me error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'db.statistics.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `statistics` where `date` between 2019-10-15 00:00:00 and 2019-10-22 00:00:00 and `user_id` = 2 group by `ip`)

Comment: Thank you. When I have enable strict mode and run yours code - I have error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'db.statistics.company_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `company_id`, `agent`, `ip` from `statistics` where `date` between 2019-10-15 00:00:00 and 2019-10-22 00:00:00 and `user_id` = 2 group by `ip`). I prefer enable this option. When I set false to Stricklands mode - I have result 0

Comment: not sure how is that possible :) could you update your question with some of your entries from your database? like a few rows, feel free to change values, I just want to have look at it